Type hinting with custom type definition failed
I try to type my vars and provide to a method. With the following  type definitions and objects the type hinting failed.
Type definitions:
// dummy.ts

type simpleObjectType = {
    [key:string]: object|string
}

type objectArrayType = Array<simpleObjectType>|[];

type multiTypedObjectType = {
    [key:string]: string|null|objectArrayType
}

type dummyType = {
    [key:string]: string|simpleObjectType|multiTypedObjectType
}

...

Object:
// dummy.ts
...
const dummySimpleObject:simpleObjectType = {
    test: '123'
}

const dummyObjectArray:objectArrayType = [
    {
        test: 'name'
    },
    {
        test: 'name'
    }
];

const dummyMultiTypedObject:multiTypedObjectType = {
    meta: null,
    illnies: dummyObjectArray
}


const dummyObject:dummyType = {
    str: "bcd",
    simpleObject:dummySimpleObject,
    multiTypedObject: dummyMultiTypedObject
}
...

Now I try to extract typed attributes from object above:
// dummy.ts
...
const currentString:string = dummyObject.str;

const currentSimpleObject:simpleObjectType = dummyObject.simpleObject;

const currentMultiTypedObject:multiTypedObjectType = dummyObject.multiTypedObject;

Even though the attributes are in their setter with defined type, on the getter the type hint throws errors (e.g. const currentString:string = dummyObject.string):
Type 'string | simpleObjectType | multiTypedObjectType' is not assignable to type 'simpleObject'.
Type 'simpleObjectType' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

As I understand, I define the dummyObject with the dummyType, which allowed multiple types. Am I wrong? How to define the types, to make it work as expected (typed vars like defined)?

Annotations throw away information you apparently care about; if you want TS to preserve that, don't annotate. You can use satisfies instead, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll find a suitable duplication source for this question. If not, what am I missing?

Honestly i don't understand your answer, maybe in the context. For now i just care about the typescript hinting, not the compiled JS...

Sorry about, i haven't seen the satisfies operator... a small string in a lot of code ;-). Thx, i will update the question with your solution

for a better printing maybe? Otherwise there is only a question without answer, only comments...

• Please don't do that; such an edit will likely be rolled back. • This question has been closed as a duplicate, see the related questions and answers for more information.
